# Objective C method being called when returning to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

The basic question I have is: What would cause a method to be called automagically when returning to the foreground?  Are there things that make methods susceptible to being called when returning to foreground?

Here's what happens:
Using AVQueuePlayer.
Pause the playback.
Switch to another app.
Come back to first app.
The method that calls - (void)play; is called when we return to the foreground every time.

I don't think that this has anything to do with AVFoundation but that's what's happening when we return.

[image: Stack Trace]

Thanks

Comment: What did the documentation say?

Comment: Have you found anything interesting by placing a breakpoint in `-play;` and looking at the stack trace?

Comment: "The method that calls play" plus the rest of the stack would be useful to know

Comment: "What did the documentation say?" - Nothing that helps as far as I can see.  I'm asking here after getting all I could understand from the docs.

"Have you found anything interesting by ..." - Nothing.  Did that and and the stack trace doesn't show me anything as far as I can see.  But I did forget to put the screen shot in so I will add it now.

""The method that calls play" plus the ..." - Yep.  My bad. added the screen shot.

Comment: Interestingly:
mp3 file #1 is a podcast.  This one experiences this behavior.
mp3 file #2 is just a song.  It does not experience this behavior.
Are podcasts encoded differently somehow or have metadata that would cause this?
Strange.

Comment: Said another way: Does the metadata of a podcast (Media Kind type perhaps?) in combination with AVQueuePlayer make the OS behave differently so that it thinks it needs to continue playing on resuming to the foreground?  Can't find any documentation of that but that seems to be what's happening.

Comment: Confirmed.  I changed a regular mp3's media kind to Podcast and it began having the same behavior.  But makes that happen?  Strange.

Comment: Regarding the stack trace.  You can get the entire trace for thread 1 by using the slider at the bottom in Xcode.  The missing numbers 2-7 would be worth seeing.   The other threads don't appear to matter.